# VBA to delete rows based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do the following :

- VBA to lookup a value from a particular cell
- Match these values in a particular column in specified sheets
- Delete all rows from the sheet if the value do not match

I have tried the following - the code doesn't seem to function

```
Sub Delete()
    Dim List As Variant
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim r As Long
    List = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(28, "C").Value
    LR = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = LR To 1 Step -1
        If IsError(Application.Match(Range("E" & r).Value, List, False)) Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:AA36429").Rows(r).Delete
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Description "the code doesn't seem to function" is too vague. Could you please [edit] the question and add explanation what exact issues do you have with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Delete()    

Dim i As Integer
Dim LR As Long
Dim List As Variant

LR = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
List = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(28, "C").Value   

For i = 1 To LR
    If Cells(i, "E").Value = List Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Quick question what if I want the list to be array would the code still work.

Comment: Short answer is yes, but are you looking for a fixed length array or a variable size? Also, how are you going to feed values to the array?

Comment: Fixed length - 2

Comment: Dim Ar As Variant
    Ar = Range("A1:A2").Value

Comment: I have 3 sheets with about 30K rows in them , this script is running a long time and I had to kill the file ( ~1 hr). Are there any suggestions for optimizing

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few ways of going about this, but the quickest way I know of is to use MATCH to compare values in a range to values in an array. Please note that this has a limit to 4000 or so values to compare before it fails. For your purposes, I think the following will work:

```
Sub test1()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim array1() As Variant
    Dim array2() As Variant

    array1 = Array("ABC", "XYX")
    array2 = Range("A1:A2")

    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(Range("A1").Value, array1, 0)) Then
        x = 1
    ElseIf IsNumeric(Application.Match(Range("A1").Value, array2, 0)) Then
        x = IsNumeric(Application.Match(Range("A1").Value, array2, 0))
    End If

    'If x is not found in these arrays, x will be 0.
    MsgBox x
End Sub
```

Another similar way is the following:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim array1() As Variant
    Dim FilterArray() As String
    Dim x As Variant

    x = Range("A1").Value
    array1 = Array("ABC", "RANDOM", "VBA")

    FilterArray = Filter(SourceArray:=array1, _
                          Match:=strText, _
                          Include:=True, _
                          Compare:=vbTextCompare)

    If UBound(FindOutArray) = -1 Then
        MsgBox "No, Array doesn't contain this item - " & x
    Else
        MsgBox "Yes, Array contains this item - " & x
    End If

End Sub
```

So if we were to incorporate that all together (and I tested this btw):

```
Sub Delete()

Dim i As Integer
Dim LR As Long
Dim List() As Variant
Dim x As Long

LR = Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
List = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").Value

For i = 1 To LR
    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(Cells(i, "E").Value, List, 0)) Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "E").Value = ""
    End If
Next i

Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells.Delete

End Sub
```

This will set the cells that have values that are found in the array to blanks. Once the loop is finished, then the blank cells are deleted. If you want to shift the entire rows up, then use this as the last line instead:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```